# how to get 12 hrs format with AM/PM using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```js
$scope.timePickerObject12Hour = {
      inputEpochTime: ((new Date()).getHours() * 60 * 60 + 3600),  //Optional
      step: 15,  //Optional
      format: 12,  //Optional
      //titleLabel: '12-hour Format',  //Optional
      closeLabel: 'Close',  //Optional
      setLabel: 'Set',  //Optional
      setButtonType: 'button-positive',  //Optional
      closeButtonType: 'button-stable',  //Optional
      callback: function (val) {    //Mandatory
        timePicker12Callback(val);
      }
    };

    

    function timePicker12Callback(val) {
      if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
    
        console.log('Time not selected');
      } else {
   
        $scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime = val;
  console.log(val);
        var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
       
      }
  
    }
```

i have used angular and ionic app.here i have followed this gitup https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker for time picker .when i select time(for example i have selected 5pm)console i am getting value 61200 like this or 
Selected epoch is :  61200 and the time is  17 : 0 in UTC how can i convert this to 12hrs format with AM/PM format any one help me out

```
$scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime = val;
        console.log(val);
        var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
        console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), ':', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'in UTC');
```

Comment: Post complete code please

Comment: Hi, did you get this solved? Having fits with this ionic plugin. Keeps giving dates in the past when parsing date.

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
var yourDateObject = new Date();
var amPmHour = $filter('date')(yourDateObject, 'hh');
```

**Don't forget to invoke the *$filter* module for that.**

From [Angularjs Date documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: Wherever you want... That will give you the date in Am/Pm format.

Comment: i am asking only time